# Spring - factory for prototype beans implementing same interface with varying dependencies and arguments

Tags: java, spring

I have an interface which is implemented by several classes. Those implementation have different bean dependencies as well as varying required parameters. I want the factory method creating these implementations to take only parameters which are not Spring beans as parameters. Beans should be injected by usual Spring magic.

Let the following snippet present the problem I am facing

```java
// interface
public interface Command {
    String getAction();
}

// implementations
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CopyCommand implements Command {
    private final CopyService copyService;  // BEAN
    private final String content;           // any STRING param

    @Override
    public String getAction() { return "COPY";}
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PasteCommand implements Command {
    private final PasteService pasteService; // BEAN

    @Override
    public String getAction() { return "PASTE";}
}

// factory
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CommandFactory {
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    // args - zero or more, non-bean parameters (like content in CopyCommand)
    public Command createCommand(Class<? extends Command> clazz, Object... args) {
        // (zero or more) BEANs injected, args forwarded
        return context.getBean(clazz, args); 
    }
}
```

The code above returns `BeanCreationException: Could not resolve matching constructor` when calling `factory.createCommand(CopyCommand.class, "some text")`. I understand that it's probably looking for `CopyService` instance in the `args` and I am wondering whether there is a Spring way to get it working as I need.

Comment: What is the constructor? Is it autowiring?

Comment: Yep, I'm using RequiredArgsConstructor annotation from Lombok, it does the Autowire-ing